# Angular - Delete row from async pipe

Tags: angular, observable, angular-pipe

The most common way to delete a row from an array is

```
this.countries.splice(pos, 1);
```

You have an array "countries" and you delete 1 element from the position "pos".

How about if we use async pipe?

```
countries$ = this.areasService.getCountries();


*ngFor="let c of (countries$ | async); let i=index"
```

How can I delete the element from the position "pos"? There is no array to delete from...

Comment: Hi again. You can't delete from an Observable, it has no buffer, nor does it keep track of what elements have been sent once it sends them. 
You could use a real list and get rid of ` asynPipe`, or use a filter based on some criteria.

Comment: you can have a dynamic refreshing of the elements inside `*ngFor` without using asyncPipe. Check my answer.

Comment: When you say "delete", do you mean "not show in the view"? Can we have more context about the `ngFor` loop (e.g. the type of element on which it is applied)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete from an Observable. It has no buffer, nor does it keep track of what elements have been sent once it sends them.

You could use an array, and the fact that angular detect changes on assignment :

```
countries = []
```

**onInit**

```
this.areasService.getCountries().subscribe( val=> this.countries =val);
```

**html**

```
*ngFor="let c of countries; let i=index"
```

**Important**:

when you splice, you should reassign this.countries in order to trigger change detection.

```
deleteEl(pos){
  this.countries.splice(pos, 1);
  this.countries = [...this.countries];
}
```